# How to remove strings from Colum A from strings of Colum B

Tags: python, pandas, substring, concatenation

Wonder if you have two Columns (A = 'Name', B = 'Name_Age'), is there a quick way to remove 'Name' from 'Name_Age' so that you can quickly get 'Age', like a reversed concatenation??

I've thought about 'string split', but in some cases (when there's no string split factor) I really need a method to remove strings of one column from strings of another.

```
#example data below:

import pandas as pd

data =  {'Name':['Mark','Matt','Michael'], 'Name_Age':['Mark 14','Matt 29','Michael 18']}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try using pandas `apply` function, which lets you define your own function to be passed to every row of the dataframe:

```py
def age_from_name_age(name, name_age):
    return name_age.replace(name, '').strip()

df['Age'] = df.apply(lambda x: age_from_name_age(x['Name'], x['Name_Age']),
                     axis='columns')
```

`age_from_name_age` takes two strings (a name and a name_age), and returns just the age. Then, in the apply statement, I define an anonymous lambda function that just takes in a row and passes the correct fields to `age_from_name_age`.

Answer (score 1):

Using string slicing:

```
df['Age'] = df.apply(lambda row: row['Name_Age'][len(row['Name']):], axis=1).astype(int)
```

Comment: This is nice solution with lambda +1

Answer (score 1):

You can use `str.split()` to separate the values from the column names with space separator and then rename the column's with new names.

### 1) Using `str.split()`

```
>>> df['Name_Age'].str.split(" ", expand=True).rename(columns={0:'Name', 1:'Age'})
      Name Age
0     Mark  14
1     Matt  29
2  Michael  18
```

OR

```
>>> df = df['Name_Age'].str.split(" ", expand=True).rename(columns={0:'Name', 1:'Age'})
>>> df
      Name Age
0     Mark  14
1     Matt  29
2  Michael  18
```

OR, by Converting the splitted list into new dataframe:

```
>>> pd.DataFrame(df.Name_Age.str.split().tolist(), columns="Name Age".split())
      Name Age
0     Mark  14
1     Matt  29
2  Michael  18
```

### 2) Another option using `str.partition`

```
>>> df['Name_Age'].str.partition(" ", True).rename(columns={0:'Name', 2:'Age'}).drop(1, axis=1)
      Name Age
0     Mark  14
1     Matt  29
2  Michael  18
```

### 3) another using `df.assign` with `lambda`

Use  `split()` with default separator as follows and assigning the values back with new column `Age`.

```
>>> df.assign(Age = df.Name_Age.apply(lambda x: x.split()[1]))
      Name    Name_Age Age
0     Mark     Mark 14  14
1     Matt     Matt 29  29
2  Michael  Michael 18  18

OR

>>> df.Name_Age.apply(lambda x: pd.Series(str(x).split())).rename({0:"Name",1:"Age"}, axis=1)
      Name Age
0     Mark  14
1     Matt  29
2  Michael  18
```

Comment: this is nice, this helped as i was looking for `split` and `rename`. `df.assign` will create a copy of the original df?